# Como puedo obtener un arreglo hecho en jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Explicaré lo que quiero hacer, yo desde un archivo js creo un array en el cual le voy generando indices asociativos(si es que así se les puede llamar). Después de crear el arreglo intento mandarlo por ajax aun archivo php, pero al intentar recibir el array me viene vacio, intenté con JSON.stringify() antes de mandarlo y recibiendolo con un json_decode() pero no me funcionó.

Este es mi código en js(diculpen si mi codigo es algo turbio aun soy un novato en esto, gracias)

```
var array_datos = [];

function llenarArreglo()
{
    if(array_datos[unidad] === undefined) array_datos[unidad] = [];
    if(array_datos[unidad]['Apartado'] === undefined) array_datos[unidad]['Apartado'] = [];
    if(array_datos[unidad]['Apartado']['Fecha'] === undefined) array_datos[unidad]['Apartado']['Fecha'] = [];
    if(array_datos[unidad]['Apartado']['Valor'] === undefined) array_datos[unidad]['Apartado']['Valor'] = [];

    if(array_datos[unidad]['Apartado']['Fecha'][cont] === undefined)
    {
       array_datos[unidad]['Apartado']['Fecha'][cont] = fecha;
    }
    if(array_datos[unidad]['Apartado']['Valor'][cont] === undefined)
    {
      array_datos[unidad]['Apartado']['Valor'][cont] = valor;
    }
};

$('#boton_guardar').on('click', function(){
    var obj = $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'procesar.php',
        data: {
            evento: 'guardar',
            datos: array_datos
        },
        beforeSend: function(){

        }
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

y en PHP lo recibo de esta manera

```
$evento = filter_input('INPUT_POST', 'evento');
switch($evento)
{
    case 'guardar':
        $datos = filter_input('INPUT_POST', 'datos', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
        print_r($datos);
    break;
}
```

Comment: `filter_input` recibe un `int`, no un `String`. Quita las comillas: `$evento = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'evento');`

Comment: En tu ejemplo, la variable unidad no está declarada. ¿Toma valores de tipo number o de tipo string? Lo que tengo claro es que array_datos[unidad] tiene claves de tipo string, por lo que es un array asociativo. Si es un array asociativo deberías instanciarlo así: if(array_datos[unidad] != null) array_datos[unidad] = {};

Comment: si `array_datos` es realmente un array, nunca se va a cumplir que `array_datos[100]` (por ejemplo) sea `undefined`. Si no se ha definido ese elemento, será `null`. Si `array_datos` es un objeto (i.e. `unidad` es un texto y no un número, como sospecho) , entonces debieras definir `array_datos={};` y en ese caso sí tendrás un `undefined`. Finalmente, para inicializar cada elemento de tu array, debes hacer `array_datos[unidad] = {}`; porque claramente ese es un objeto (la llave `Apartado` ya te dice que el índice no es numérico.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos por su apoyo y amenadiel gracias por tu respuesta, esa fue la que me dio la clave para solucionar mi problema, tenias razón, lo que pasa es que estaba declarando como array mi variable principal y al ir inicializando las propiedades las ponia como array tambien, cambie todo por {} y ya pude obtener los datos datos necesarios. 
Muchas gracias

saludos!!!